# MATLAB - Convert vector to matrix

Tags: matlab

How could I convert vector in MATLAB to this specific type of matrix? Number of columns will be a parameter.

[image: matrix]

Comment: You want to reshape the vector? `reshape` it then. Consider reading the documentation/using a search engine before asking in SO, basic "tutorial"-like questions are off topic

Comment: it is not just a reshape since some values are duplicated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can build (once for all) a matrix with the indices (1:L on first column, 1:K on first row, etc), then simply do a selection from the data vector based on those indices

```
% matrix containing the indices 
indices = bsxfun(@plus,(0:L-1)',(0:K-1)) + 1; % L-by-K matrix
% now get the data from the vector, based on the indices
X=x(indices);
```